# How to get the global y-value of a list of vertices?

Tags: python, scripting, vertices

I am afraid the solution is very simple but I don't get it :(

I need to extract the smallest global Y-coordinate out of a list of vertices. I tried it like this but the result isn't quite right:

```
vert_list = [bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world * vert.co for vert in bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices]

min_value = [min(vert_list)]

print(min_value[::1])
```

On the one hand the given value is wrong and on the second hand I get all three coordinates, not just the y value.

Do you have a tip for me?

Comment: Try `min_value = min([ co.z for co in vert_list ])`

Comment: Great, thanks TLousky! Works quite as I need it.